# How to calculate this integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}dx＝I＝?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}dx＝I＝?$ without using taylor expansion

Any hint will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$I = \int^{\infty}_{0}x\times \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}dx = \int^{\infty}_{0}x\cdot \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}e^{-nx}dx = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\int^{\infty}_{0}x\cdot e^{-nx}dx$$
Using Integration by parts, We get

$$I = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left[x\cdot \frac{e^{-nx}}{-n}\right]|_{0}^{\infty}+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}\int^{\infty}_{n=1}e^{-nx}dx$$

So $$I = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}(e^{-nx})|^{\infty}_{0} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} = \zeta(2)$$